# how to persist an object in android?

Tags: java, android, caching, persistence

I have read some post regarding persistence methods in android

but it still unclear to me how we can persist an object?

please relate to session-persistence and application-lifetime presistence

1) persist an object as long as the app is installed => i guess it means using SQlite or sharePreferences. but I want to save an object without flattening it to key-value pairs.

2) persist an object for a session (meaning since the app is up till the user quits it) ==> I would use static variable. Any other native caching mechanism ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into using [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and saving the objects to files locally.

Here is oracle's tutorial on serialization using this method: [Oracle tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)

Comment: please relate to session-persistence and application-lifetime presistence

Comment: This would still apply for those situations, try checking out the tutorial. You can serialize an object and do so much more from there. Alternatively you can make your own serialization (Build class from a string value, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The standard java way of doing that would be `Serializable`, but for Android, `Parcelable` is much more [efficient](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) and thus recommended.

You could use that for any object saving, be it between or while app sessions.